# A nifty way of finding starting location for all occurances of a sub string or a Regexp in Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, string

Let us say that I have this string:

```
bar="hello kohello hello"
```

I would like a function foo that I give it

```
foo(bar,"hello")
```

And get:

```
[0,8,14]
```

Now, I could just do (1 of many options):

```
def foo(str1,substr)
  i= -1
  substr_length = substr.length()
  str1.chars.map{ | char |
    i+=1
    str1(i,substr_length) == substr ? i : nil
  }.select{ |x| x }
end
```

Is there something more "Ruby like"? Also with Regexp, rather than strings.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In `irb`

```
arr = []
bar.scan("hello"){arr.push($~.offset(0)[0])}
```

now check arr

`[0,8,14]`

Adding my consoles' code for clarity

```
1.9.3-p362 :008 > arr = []
 => [] 
1.9.3-p362 :009 > bar.scan("hello"){arr.push($~.offset(0)[0])}
 => "hello kohello hello" 
1.9.3-p362 :010 > arr
 => [0, 8, 14]
```

for those who dont know this cryptic ruby global variable.

`$~` contains the `MatchData` from the previous successful pattern match.
so it is similar to `Regexp.last_match`

for finding the index, we can find the `Regexp.last_match.offset(0)[0]`

Comment: Though what? What is the gotacha?

Comment: that was just left from the last edit ..sorry'

Comment: @user1134991 is the solution working for you ?

Comment: @user1134991 ah dont forget to upvote, help me complete my 1k ;)

Comment: It is working. Very well.